# Rails: random already initialized constant X + previous definition of X

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.1, rails-5.1.6

Ruby: 2.5.1, Rails: 5.1.6

Occasionally, this error only appears in the development environment. And on multiple platforms. Whether ruby is installed on "rbenv" or "rvm".

```
Started GET "/notifications" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-27 14:51:47 +0200
Processing by NotificationsController#index as */*
Started GET "/dashboard_widgets/my_courses/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-27 14:51:47 +0200
Started GET "/dashboard_widgets/appointments/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-27 14:51:47 +0200
Started GET "/dashboard_widgets/calendars/4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-27 14:51:47 +0200
Started GET "/dashboard_widgets/tasks/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-27 14:51:47 +0200
  Account Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`subdomain` = '' LIMIT 1
  User Load (61.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`account_id` = 1 AND `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  AccountSetting Load (1.3ms)  SELECT `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`target_id` = 1 AND `settings`.`target_type` = 'Account'
/Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457: warning: already initialized constant DashboardWidgets
/Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457: warning: previous definition of DashboardWidgets was here
/Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457: warning: already initialized constant DashboardWidgets
/Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457: warning: previous definition of DashboardWidgets was here
/Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457: warning: already initialized constant DashboardWidgets
/Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457: warning: previous definition of DashboardWidgets was here



LoadError (Unable to autoload constant DashboardWidgets::MyCoursesController, expected /Users/alexander/rails_projects/tutorize-business-solutions/app/controllers/dashboard_widgets/my_courses_controller.rb to define it):

Processing by DashboardWidgets::TasksController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant DashboardWidgets::AppointmentsController, expected /Users/alexander/rails_projects/tutorize-business-solutions/app/controllers/dashboard_widgets/appointments_controller.rb to define it):
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant DashboardWidgets::CalendarsController, expected /Users/alexander/rails_projects/tutorize-business-solutions/app/controllers/dashboard_widgets/calendars_controller.rb to define it):
appsignal (2.3.7) lib/appsignal/rack/rails_instrumentation.rb:17:in `call'

appsignal (2.3.7) lib/appsignal/rack/rails_instrumentation.rb:17:in `call'
   (7.9ms)  SET NAMES utf8mb4,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483

appsignal (2.3.7) lib/appsignal/rack/rails_instrumentation.rb:17:in `call'
  Account Load (21.9ms)  SELECT  `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`subdomain` = '' LIMIT 1
  User Load (2.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`account_id` = 1 AND `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  AccountSetting Load (1.3ms)  SELECT `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`target_id` = 1 AND `settings`.`target_type` = 'Account'
  DashboardWidget Load (4.5ms)  SELECT  `dashboard_widgets`.* FROM `dashboard_widgets` WHERE `dashboard_widgets`.`account_id` = 1 AND `dashboard_widgets`.`id` = 3 ORDER BY `dashboard_widgets`.`position` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendering dashboard_widgets/tasks/show.html.erb
  DashboardWidgetShare Load (3.5ms)  SELECT  `dashboard_widget_shares`.* FROM `dashboard_widget_shares` WHERE `dashboard_widget_shares`.`account_id` = 1 AND `dashboard_widget_shares`.`dashboard_widget_id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  Task Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  `tasks`.* FROM `tasks` WHERE `tasks`.`account_id` = 1 AND `tasks`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `tasks`.`user_id` = 1 AND `tasks`.`status` = 'opened' ORDER BY `tasks`.`due_date` DESC LIMIT 10
  Rendered dashboard_widgets/tasks/layouts/_widget.html.erb (39.1ms)
  Rendered dashboard_widgets/tasks/show.html.erb (82.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 959ms (Views: 116.0ms | ActiveRecord: 51.2ms)
```

The paths for `my_courses_controller.rb` and all other controllers are correct and double checked. The strange thing is that as soon as a second request comes, everything works. The production environment does not seem to be a problem so far.
The rails `autoload_path` has not been extended.

Some example code of the structure:

```
module DashboardWidgets
  class WidgetsController < ::ApplicationController
    private

    def set_user
      # sets user and stuff...
    end
  end
end

module DashboardWidgets
  class MyCoursesController < WidgetsController
    include CustomView
    layout false

    def show
      authorize [:dashboard_widgets, :my_course]
      set_dashboard_widget
      set_user
      search = Searches::LmsSearch.new current_user.learning_course_ids_by_type.merge(search_params)
      @courses = search.search

      render_custom_view
    end

    ...

end
```

We searched for the common "already initialized constant X" Errors and "previous definition of X" warnings for weeks and now I have absolutely no idea what the problem may still be.